# Mocha / Node: how to use assert.rejects()?

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, node-assert

I tried to followed the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message) in order to test for the error message using assert.rejects (I do have Node above v10).

But it's always passing, even with a ridiculous message. What am I doing wrong?

```
it("should fail but it's not", 
  async ()=> {
    let itemId = 'not an id'
    assert.rejects( 
      await ListRepo.checkById(itemId),
      {message: 'abracadabra'}                        
    )
  }
)
```

UPDATE:
It seems that if I return the assert.rejects, it works. But I still don't know the reason.

Comment: [Returning a `Promise`](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) (or using the `done` parameter) in Mocha signals to it that the test is asynchronous so the test waits for the Promise to resolve/reject. That's why it works when you return it. Otherwise the test runs immediately and ends before your `assert.rejects` actually returns a result.

Comment: `await assert.rejects(..)`

Comment: Did U solve this? I don't understand the docs either.

Comment: Yes, you just have to return a promise. And the explanation is given by Nik, above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I write this, everything written above/previously is correct, but much of it is needlessly complicated.  It is correct that you must return a promise, so that mocha itself has something to wait for, otherwise it returns immediately (before your promise can resolve or reject).  The missing piece is that manually waiting for a promise is rarely what you actually want to do here.

This simplest pattern is hinted at by @caub in a comment--await the promise returned by `assert.rejects`.  Specifically:

```
it("should fail but it's not", 
  async ()=> {
    let itemId = 'not an id'
    await assert.rejects( 
      ListRepo.checkById(itemId),
      {message: 'abracadabra'}                        
    )
  }
)
```

There are three key things here:

1. The test function itself must be `async`.
2. `await` the `assert.rejects` call inside the (async) test function.  This automatically makes the test function return `Promise<void>`, which is exactly what you want.  This puts the important part right at the point of the assert call, and compared to manually returning/handling a promise, makes it easier to copy/paste the call elsewhere and makes it easier to assert multiple rejections in one test.
3. *Do not* `await` what you're passing into the `rejects` call.  You should be passing in a promise--not an `await`ed value.

Comment: My test passes but I still get the error in the console. How can I prevent this?

Comment: @MatthiasMax Impossible to say without seeing your code.  You should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

What nicholaswmin said is correct, but there's a "rest of the owl" moment here that I'd like to clear-up.

If your desire is: "I want to assert reject", *i.e.* "I want to make sure this code rejects in the right way," the pattern is a bit complicated.

First off, write in `return fxnWhichReturnsPromise()`. The test will fail if your function is rejecting, and you want the inverse of that. You have to use the two-argument signature of `.then()`, which looks like: `.then(onFulfillCallback, onRejectCallback)`, since if you split it into `.then` & `.catch`, failing in the `.then`-block will be caught by the subsequent `.catch`-block, and what should be a failing test (it did not reject) will be a passing one.

In practice, altogether it looks something like this:

```
it('rejects when given foobar', () => {
  return fxnThatShouldReject(foobar)
    .then(
      (val) => { assert.fail(`Should have rejected, returned with ${val} instead`)
      ,
      (err) => { assert.equal(err.message, "Rejection reason I was expecting") }
    )
})
```

The reason the assertion library does not have a built-in assertion handler for this is because being able to "hold-up" asynchronous execution in the test suite is really a test-runner capability. `assert.throws()` is synchronous, by contrast.